# In Jade,is there a way to get a widget to float on the left without introducing a css style?

Tags: pug

I have a button written in Jade; the button is written into a span. I have a Java Script widget attached to the Jade button.   I am trying to get the widget written in Java Script to float on the left side of a button.  Is there a way to get the widget to float on the left without introducing a css style?

Answer (score 1):

Jade is a *template engine*, it does not style elements, so your question is kind of off-topic.
If you want an element to float, you should use inline *HTML* elements, or as you suggested, *CSS styling*.

But it does not depend on the template engine, you would use the same solutions if you were using Handlebars, EJS, Mustache or whatever.